# Populate dropdown based on other dropdown in Postback

Tags: c#, combobox, telerik, multi-select

I have two multiselect dropdowns and one has to bind based on the other.

```
  public void PopulateStatus()
{       
    string status=ddlstatus.Text;
    ddlname.DataSource = spObj.sp_Name(status);
    ddlname.DataTextField = "status";
    ddlname.DataValueField = "status";
    ddlname.DataBind();      

}

             foreach (RadComboBoxItem itm in ddlstatus.Items)
             {
            itm.Checked = true;

             }
            foreach (RadComboBoxItem itm in ddlname.Items)
                {
                itm.Checked = true;
                       }
```

All the above code is called in Postback.But the issue is I am not able to capture  ddlstatus.Text; in the PopulateStatus() method.

Can someone suggest any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

try `ddlstatus.SelectedItem.Text` instead.

Comment: Its not working...is it possible to capture the selected item outside the buttonclick event..?not sure...i can capture them in buttonclicks ..but not in postback..:(

Comment: Have you tried using a SelectedIndexChanged on the first dropdownlist to fill the second drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind ComboBox etc if not page post back happened.

in page load method

```
if (!Page.IsPostBack)
{
   // bind controls 
}
```

Comment: ya i did there only.. if (!IsPostBack)...but its not capturing the ddlstatus.Text;